# Importing Ansible module utils

Tags: python, coding-style, python-import, ansible

The Ansible [module development documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html) states:

> Key parts [of writing an Ansible module] include always ending the module file with:
>
> ```
> from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
> main()
> ```

This contradicts the usual practice of grouping imports at the top of the file.  Using `import *` also prevents lint tools (e.g. flake8) from working effectively, and is [generally regarded as bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714).

Is there any reason to import in this way, or is Ansible just making their own style recommendation here?

Comment: Ansible is just making it up as they go along. Ignore them and do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: The below answer no longer pertains to Ansible 2.1+. From the comments:

*I realize this is an old post but should anyone still be interested, it's worth noting that this is not true anymore since ansible 2.1. Taken from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules.html): Prior to Ansible-2.1.0, importing only what you used from ansible.module_utils.basic did not work. You needed to use a wildcard import - [bouletta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5556887/bouletta)*

**Original Answer**

Ansible ([prior to version 2.1](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules.html#common-module-boilerplate)) [will refuse to run](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_common.py#L118) if you don't do the `import *` business. I'm not 100% certain *what* magic is being done, but I know [*some*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_common.py#L39-L57) is.

> The Replacer is used to insert chunks of code into modules before
>     transfer.  Rather than doing classical python imports, this allows for more
>     efficient transfer in a no-bootstrapping scenario by not moving extra files
>     over the wire, and also takes care of embedding arguments in the transferred
>     modules.
>
> This version is done in such a way that local imports can still be
>     used in the module code, so IDEs don't have to be aware of what is going on.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
> ```
>
> ... will result in the insertion basic.py into the module
>     from the module_utils/ directory in the source tree.
>
> All modules are required to import at least basic, though there will also
>     be other snippets.

Comment: @augurar I realize this is an old post but should anyone still be interested, it's worth noting that this is not true anymore since ansible 2.1.
Taken from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules.html) : 
Prior to Ansible-2.1.0, importing only what you used from ansible.module_utils.basic did not work. You needed to use a wildcard import